# how to append list of DOM elements objects to another list of DOM element objects

Tags: python, dom

I have listed some DOM elements from a XML file and kept in list1.

```
list1 = [<DOM Element: DeviceInfo at 0x1915c88>, <DOM Element: ManagementServer at 0x1961b70>, <DOM Element: GatewayInfo at 0x19cd5d0>]
```

I have another list2, which also has DOM elements objects,

```
list2 = [<DOM Element: VendorConfigFile__INSTANCE__ at 0x1915f08>, <DOM Element: SupportedDataModel__INSTANCE__ at 0x191bda0>]
```

i want to append the list2 to list1.
I use the command.

```
newList = list1.append(list2)
```

expected output:

```
newList = [<DOM Element: DeviceInfo at 0x1915c88>, <DOM Element: ManagementServer at 0x1961b70>, <DOM Element: GatewayInfo at 0x19cd5d0>,[<DOM Element: VendorConfigFile__INSTANCE__ at 0x1915f08>, <DOM Element: SupportedDataModel__INSTANCE__ at 0x191bda0>]]
```

but I'm getting it as 'None' in the newList

what exactly is the problem and how to get this done.

Thank you

in my lists it contains `<'DOM Element:SupportedDataModel__INSTANCE__ at 0x191bda0'>` and many such DOM element objects, contents inside `<>` are not displayed inside the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated!**

return type of append is `None`.
so `list1.append(list2)` gives out `None` but also changes `list1`.
so you should do.

```
newList = list(list1)
newList.append(list(list2))
```

Comment: hi Dinesh, i want it exactly like lists of lists: my new list should look like, newList = [ list1 , [list2] ]

Comment: If your `list1` and `list2` doesn't contain lists with in them, you can use this. else use `deepcopy()` instead of `list()`